# I have an issue with field label translation

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

I am working in a multilingual website (French, English, German) with french as default language.

[image]

Then I installed the module internationalization + field translation.

Globally, everything works fine. The translate interface is do its job. The issue comes with field labels.

I setup all fields (more than 300) in french language, so the client would be able to translate the labels in english + german through the translate interface (admin/config/regional/translate/translate). Apparently the problem is that Drupal detects field labels as being in english language, instead french as expected.

[image]

For example in this picture, you can see that label "surface en m2" is detected as an english text.

This is weird because when I am in edit form page, the content seems detected as french (original text).

[image]

Anyone was confronted to this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Could you try settings language source for string translations in i18n? In the menu - Configuration » Regional and language » Multilingual settings » Strings and then "String Translation source language"

Comment: This did solve the problem for me (setting it to English). But the behavior is still inconsistent, and I would consider it a bug. Probably already known and reported, I just don't know what to search for.

Comment: indeed this is a bug linked to the Token module. here is the patch https://www.drupal.org/node/2474403 (commited in the -dev version)